# Ordering resultset in specific order

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to group my resultset with "NY" entries first then any other state entries which might be returned.

Example:

```
OrderID   State   Type   
----------------------------           
123       CA      Checque
123       NY      ELectronic
222       JC      Checque
123       NY      Checque
```

`OrderID` is the primary key

Result set needs to look like:

```
OrderID   State   Type    
----------------------------
123       NY      ELectronic
123       NY      Checque     
123       CA      Checque
```

For user with `OrderID = 123`

It works if I do below but Is it possible to do the same without using union.

I am doing this for a large set of records.

It works using:

```
Select * from Table1 where orderid = 123 and State = 'NY'
Union
Select * from Table1 where orderid = 123 and State <> 'NY'
```

Using SQL Server 2008

Thanks

Comment: Fyi, the union approach has no chance of working because there is no order by at the end. Union does not just concat the result sets, it has no ordering guarantees by itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this at the end of your query:

```
order by (case when state = 'NY' then 0 else 1 end),
         state
```

The fact that the `union` works is happenstance -- not at all guaranteed.  The only way to order results is by specifying an `order by` clause at the outermost level of a query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `case` statement to get `'NY'` to the top and then by `State` and `Type desc` like below:

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/39a2a/3)**

```
select OrderID, State, Type
from T
where orderID = 123
order by case when State = 'NY' then '0' else State end, Type desc
```